# Can we set a self hosted agent to several organizations?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Is it possible to create a self-hosted agent and assign it to several organizations on azure devops?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no, you can install multiple parallell agents on the same self-hosted server and configure them to connect to different organizations. But one single agent can only connect to one organization.

Just unpack the agent zip file to two different folders and configure each one with the organisation URLs, authentication method and other settings. This way you get two agent services running side by side serving the two organizations.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, does that mean one VM can be assigned to two organizations if we unzip the agent file in two folders in c drive? Trying to make it little simpler to understand and are there any con with it?

Comment: @VishalThakur, yes, you can install one agent in that VM per organization simply unziping one agent folder per organization (and configuring each one pointing to the right organization URL running Config.cmd as you can se here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent)). Main con is the fact that running several pipelines concurrently on same VM can degrade performance, but this is not a problem if it occurs rarely.